# Is there a way to map container port to a specific host port using Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

In docker we can use -p flag to map container port to whatever port required. But in kubernetes if we use use NodePort then we will get ports of host which range start from 30000. So is there a way to map to a specific port?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `nodePort` field in the service definition to specify the port for the nodeport:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport

However, a nodePort will allocate that port on all nodes in the cluster.

You can also specify a `hostPort` in the pod container spec itself, though it is not recommended:

```
ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
```

Comment: can you share the full configuration i'm getting error.

Comment: ```apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: database
  labels:
    app: db
spec:
  selector:
    app: db
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: database
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting, with what configuration?

Comment: No field such as hostPort i'm getting . What needs to be the type here.

Comment: ```error: error validating "db-vusmartmaps.yml": error validating data: ValidationError(Service.spec.ports[0]): unknown field "hostPort" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServicePort; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Comment: As I said in the answer hostPort is part of the pod/container spec, not service spec.